# Rails ActiveRecord::Base.connection to execute upon an external file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To run a one-off procedure of loading data that is already formatted for loading into postgresql

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "public"."optionsets" [...]
COMMIT;
```

Rails has the command that allows to execute raw sql

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute()
```

However, the syntax alludes to placing the syntax within the parenthesis and the documentation confirms this: "Executes the SQL statement in the context of this connection".  The following fail

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(/Users/main/optionsets.sql)
SyntaxError ((irb):3: unknown regexp options - ma)

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("/Volumes/main/optionsets.sql")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/")
LINE 1: /Users/main/optionsets.sql

location = "/Volumes/main/optionsets.sql"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(location)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/")
LINE 1: /Users/main/optionsets.sql
```

How can this be effected instead by calling an `.sql` file  `/[path_to]/optionsets.sql` ?

Comment: You have to read the file first, no? Isn't that `execute` will receive a path and read your file, it receives a string and execute it - depending on the adapter you're using

Comment: RIght. `file = File.read('/[path_to]/optionsets.sql')  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(file)`

Comment: Also, you could create migrations for the sql you need, ie function and call the function as the execute argument

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file is not effected in the above scenarios, so it must be executed beforehand.

```
file = File.read('/[path_to]/optionsets.sql')     
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

If run from the command line, then Rails also has a "dbconsole" command with a "db" alias, so you can do something like this

```
rails db < /Volumes/main/optionsets.sql
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bbd6d82dc4e00b00f07193a0c7ac3e266bce410a/guides/source/command_line.md#binrails-dbconsole